# Python loop a whole day, and when current time equals to a given time, do something

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame `df`, which has three columns(`time`, `from` and `to`). I want to execute a function which will for loop `df['time']`. When current time equals to the time in `df['time']`, call another function like print something. Each row will be executed only once. In real data, the script will be executed 24 hours in the cloud.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'time':['08:35','09:35','09:45','10:10'],
                 'from':['SHH','SZH','WXH','ZJH'],
                 'to':['NJH','NJH','NJH','NJH']})
df

    from    time    to
0   SHH     08:35   NJH
1   SZH     09:35   NJH
2   WXH     09:45   NJH
3   ZJH     10:10   NJH
```

For example, when the current time is `08:35`, print `Time is reached, train from SHH to NJH`, and when the current time is `09:35`, print `Time is reached, train from SZH to NJH`. I don't know how to modify the code below to satisfy my 
job. Need help.

```
import datetime
import time

def ex(a,b):
    print("Time is reached. train from {} to {}".format(a, b))

time_ls = list(df['time'])
from_ls = list(df['from'])
to_ls = list(df['to'])

def run():
    for i in range(len(df['time'])):
        while time.strftime("%H:%M", time.localtime()) == df['time'][i]:
            time_ls.remove(df['time'][i])
            yield ex(from_ls[i],to_ls[i])
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at [arrow](https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow) this libary makes interactions with datetimes easier and more readable.

Comment: If processing the entire dataframe every second/minute becomes too heavyweight, you might also consider setting up a scheduler based on the times you know are in there. See [sched](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html#sched.scheduler.enterabs) for something in the base libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract rows from a `pandas.DataFrame` that meet a certain condition, you want to slice the `DataFrame` instead of manually iterating over all of its rows and checking that condition on your own. The `pandas` implementation for this is way faster than any manual attempt.

Once you got the dataframe that only contains the rows that match the current time (hour and minute), you can iterate over that smaller `DataFrame` and print the result for each of its rows (since you know that it only contains those rows that match).

See the following example:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'time': ['08:35','09:35','09:45','10:10'],
        'from': ['SHH','SZH','WXH','ZJH'],
        'to':   ['NJH','NJH','NJH','NJH']})

    ct = dt.strftime(dt.now(), '%H:%M') # Get current hours and minutes
    dn = df.loc[df['time'] == ct] # Slice DataFrame based on 'time' column

    for row in dn.iterrows():
        # Iterate over all rows that meet the condition and print it
        print('{time:s} -- train from {from:s} to {to:s}.'.format(**dict(row[1])))
```

It yields (if hour and minute of `ct` string match `08:35` for this example):

```
08:35 -- train from SHH to NJH.
```

Comment: Thank you for helping .But I want to run this script a whole day. So, the script will be looped a whole day when all the rows are printed.

Comment: I hope that you want to run it once a minute using `cron`. This makes sure that you don't miss a minute and it is probably less resource consuming.

Comment: I got it, Thanks again. @jbndlr

Comment: I think you could use [shedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to achieve that if you want to stay in a pure python solution.

Comment: That's great, it's what I want. TKS,@PhML